# Error in Xcode 12.5.1 while building, (error spawnSync xcodebuild ENOBUFS)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I was running react-native project in Xcode v12.4, now I shifted my code to v12.5.1. It is giving me above error, when I build my project. What should I do?

I have googled around but not found this error regarding iOS and Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have cocoa pods installed you need to by command sudo gem install cocoapods and run following commands from your project main directory

From your project remove Pods and Podfile.lock from ios directory after that re install pods

`cd ios && pod install && cd ..`

Run your project again